# Good Call Hierarchy in Eclipse/PyDev

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

Is there a way to get a good call hierarchy in PyDev?
I want to be able to select a function and see in which files it is called and eventually by which other functions. I tried the Hierarchy View in Eclipse by pressing F4, but it does not output what I want.

Comment: I just usually do a "find in files" of `func_call()` ... there are probably better ways to do it but meh... it works

Answer (score 15, accepted):

PyDev has a find references with Ctrl+Shift+G (not sure that'd be what you're calling a call hierarchy).

Comment: It's only a simple string matching. It won't work when the function name is simple, eg. `send()`.

Comment: Well, it's not just a simple string matching -- but you're right in that given duck-typing in Python, it may be really hard to guess the real type and whether that should be a real reference or not (and when in doubt, the implementation adds such a reference instead of removing it).